# Python Regex - re.split at non white space char, how to ignore \n

Tags: python, regex

I have a test string as per the below

```
sample_string = """
object 1
 sub details 1
 sub details 2
 sub details 3
object 2
 sub details 1
 sub details 2
 sub details 3
object 3
 sub details 1
 sub details 2
 sub details 3 
 """
```

and my desired out as below

```
desired output = [
"object 1
 sub details 1
 sub details 2
 sub details 3",
"object 2
 sub details 1
 sub details 2
 sub details 3",
"object 3
 sub details 1
 sub details 2
 sub details 3"
]
```

I have a pattern which when I paste into regex101.com it works as expected, however when I run it in my shell, it looks like the new lines are being processed as \n and every line is in its own list element. I also tried using re.MULTILINE but get the same result each time. Can anyone help me with what im missing here?

Thanks

```
>>> re.split(r'^\S.+',test_string)
['\nobject 1\n sub details 1\n sub details 2\n sub details 3\nobject 2\n sub details 1\n sub details 2\n sub details 3\nobject 3\n sub details 1\n sub details 2\n sub details 3 \n ']
```

Comment: Try `re.split(r'(?m)\n(?=object \d+$)', test_string)`

Comment: Another idea: `re.findall(r'(?m)^\S.*(?:\n[^\S\n].*)*', test_string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd argument to `re.split` is `maxsplit`, not `flags`. Use keyword arguments to pass `re.MULTILINE` instead.

`re.split = split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)`

```
>>> re.split(r'^\S.+', sample_string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
['',
 '\n sub details 1\n sub details 2\n sub details 3\n',
 '\n sub details 1\n sub details 2\n sub details 3\n',
 '\n sub details 1\n sub details 2\n sub details 3']
```

Comment: OP does not need lines as separate list items, but whole blocks. See *`desired output`* in the question.